# Installing Cloud Foundry on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to install Cloud Foundry on Ubuntu 16.04.  Here are my steps:

1. curl -L "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&source=github" | tar -zx
2. ./cf --version

The result is cf version 6.18.0+b22884b-2016-05-10

I get an error message when I enter cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net

The program 'cf' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install confluence

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: Look at the difference between your use in asking for *version* and in your final use. What's different between them? (Hint: Count the number of characters actually typed in each.)

Answer (score 1):

Move the binary you downloaded (`./cf`) to somewhere on your `PATH` so you can invoke it just with `cf`.